# How to convert UUID into jdk.incubator.vector.Vector and vice versa in Java 16

Tags: java, uuid, simd

What's the best way to convert from a UUID to jdk.incubator.vector.Vector (not sure which base type, maybe Float?) and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the 'best' way since that depends on what operations you need to do on the vector afterwards and possibly your machine architecture, but a UUID could be turned into a two-element 64-bit-integer vector taking its two halves using [UUID.getLeastSignificantBits()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#getLeastSignificantBits()) and [UUID.getMostSignificantBits()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#getMostSignificantBits()):

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
LongVector vector = LongVector.fromArray(LongVector.SPECIES_128, new long[] {uuid.getLeastSignificantBits(), uuid.getMostSignificantBits()}, 0);
```

To go the other way, use [LongVector.lane()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.incubator.vector/jdk/incubator/vector/LongVector.html#lane(int)):

```
UUID x = new UUID(vector.lane(1), vector.lane(0));
```

(assuming element ordering was the same as the first example)